# I have issue with using cv2 at streamlit

Tags: python, opencv, github, streamlit, webdeploy

I create app usig streamlit that enable user to scan QR code via camera.
The app is work very well locally but when I uploaded it to GitHub and deploy at streamlit community cloud I get this error on app page:

```
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 534, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/path.py", line 4, in <module>
    import cv2
```

and this error on log file:
File "/app/path.py", line 4, in

```
import cv2
```

> ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file
> or directory

I tried to add `opencv-python` at `requirements.txt` file but it's still occure.

Comment: Please share a runnable code snippet so we can reproduce the issue